# Что скрывает yield *?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В чём разница между этими фрагментами кода?

```
yield *smth;
```

```
for (let x of smth) {
  yield x;
}
```

@torazaburo в [комментарии](//stackoverflow.com/questions/37239487/what-does-the-star-asterisk-syntax-after-a-yield-mean-in-a-recursive-generat/37239781#comment62011710_37239781) сказал

> This is an OK simplification, but it fails to address what the `yield *generator()` evaluates to, which as it turns out is the end-of-iteration value `return`'ed by the generator object. It also does not correctly represent what happens when the consumer of the generator throws into the generator, etc.

Хотелось бы узнать, в чём именно заключается разница и в каких случаях она проявит себя.

Comment: никогда не использовал yield, даже не прикину куда бы его можно было впихнуть =)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, генераторы

Comment: @Grundy я в курсе что это и приблизительно понимаю как это работает,   но пока ни разу не использовал, знаю что можно вместо callback  использовать для того чтобы приостановить выполнение функции, но как то все по старинке

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, поочерёдный проход по матрице с возможностью вернуть каждую ячейку для индивидуальной обработки - мне однажды это сэкономило кучу нервов.

Comment: @Other Спасибо посмотрю в эту сторону

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На самом деле, синтаксис `yield * gen` используется для *передачи управления* внутрь другого генератора.

Вот что об этом [говорит MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

> The yield* expression iterates over the operand and yields each value returned by it.

А вот и пример того, как это работает:

```
let seqPos = function * (max) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}

let seqNeg = function * (min) {
    let start = min > 0 ? -1*min : min;
    for (let i = start; i < 0; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}

let seq = function * (val) {
    yield * seqNeg(-1*val);
    yield 0;
    yield * seqPos(val);
}

for (let i of seq(2)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Пример выше выведет:

> -2
>   -1
>   0
>   1
>   2

А вот и [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pwbgdkt/1/) с примером.

---

Что касается основного вопроса, то разница между конструкциями:

```
for (let val of gen) {
    yield val;
}
```

и

```
yield * gen;
```

заключается в том, что в первом случае всего лишь возвращаются значения дочернего генератора, а во втором *управление полностью передается* дочернему генератору.

Это значит, что вызов методов [`Generator.prototype.next`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next), [`Generator.prototype.throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw) и [`Generator.prototype.return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) клиентским кодом на родительском генераторе будет адресован дочернему генератору:

```
let innerGen = function * () {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            console.log(yield i);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Got you!');
    }
}

let outerGen = function * () {
    let child = innerGen();
    yield * child;
}

let g = outerGen();
g.next();
g.next("foo"); // выведет в консоль "foo"
g.throw(new Error('Oops!')); // выведет "Got you!"
```

Ситуация, с пробросом исключений в дочерний итератор, описанная участником **@Роман Парадеев** в соседнем ответе, является всего лишь **частным случаем** передачи управления дочернему генератору.

Comment: @Qwertiy Смотри, какой чудесный ответ. Отметь его, пожалуйста, а свой я удалю.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев, ok, отмечу. Но удалять не надо. А ещё, уведомления так не работают.

Answer (score 5):

Вот что говорит на этот счёт говорит [ECMAScript Wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators#delegating_yield):

> This is similar to a for-in loop over the generator, except that it propagates exceptions thrown via the outer generator’s throw method into the delegated generator.

Так что разница, похоже, только в пробросе исключений.

Я набросал небольшой пример, который иллюстрирует различие:

```
function * delegate() {
    try {
        yield;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Caught by delegate');
    }
}

function * gen1() {
    console.log('Generator 1');
    try {
        yield * delegate();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Caught by generator');
    }
}

function * gen2() {
    console.log('Generator 2');
    try {
        for (let x of delegate()) {
            yield x;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Caught by generator');
    }
}

[gen1, gen2].forEach(gen => {
    const genObj = gen();
    genObj.next();
    genObj.throw('Uh oh...');
});
```

Как и ожидалось, вывод будет следующий

```
Generator 1
Caught by delegate
Generator 2
Caught by generator
```

Comment: Вызывающий код кидается исключениями внутрь вызываемого? Неожиданно. Зачем это вообще надо?

Comment: _"similar to a for-in loop"_ for-in или for-of?

Comment: В генератор можно передать данные, почему бы не передавать и исключения?

Comment: С `for-in`, скорее всего, ошибка в вики.