# Почему yield*(делегированный)для встроенных генераторов лучше обычного yield?

Tags: javascript, функции, генераторы

Суть вопроса в самом заголовке.

Comment: Где лучше? Почему вы решили, что лучше?

Comment: Вот здесь,в конце статьи такое утверждение и пример в конце со стэком мне не понятен https://learn.javascript.ru/generator

Comment: Получается,что интерпритатор не видит вложеные вызовы при обычном yeild?

Comment: И не должен видеть. yield* делегирует выполнение другому генератору, yield не делегирует, об этом написано по вашей ссылке. Встроенный генератор или не встроенный — никакого значения не имеет

Comment: Спасибо)теперь всё ясно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524750/178988

Comment: О,вот то что нужно,благодарю!